# Unable to create a link component for the entry in Navigation Management in Hybris-1811 smartedit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have followed the exact steps as described in below link to create new child node with link component but however in Link editor window when I click on save I am getting error saying

"The number of link items defined for this component has been exceeded. Only one of the following can be specified: Category, Content Page, Product, or URL."

https://help.sap.com/viewer/86dd1373053a4c2da8f9885cc9fbe55d/1811/en-US/25b673e3876343709956a61bc565b332.html

[image]

Comment: As per @Neil Hubert-Price, you need to set one of the values only. Choose either Product or URL, not both.

Answer (score 1):

The text in that page says:

> Select the target for your link. Select one of the following:
>
> - Content: An existing content page in the current content catalog version.
> - Product: An existing product page in the online version of the product
>     catalog displayed.
> - Category: An existing category pages in the online version of the product catalog displayed.
> - External Link: Link to an external URL

The error message tells you the same thing & yet you are still trying to set both Product and URL ....

Comment: Initially by seeing the error message I also thought the same. so I just selected only product but if you see that URL is mandatory field so if I leave that field empty the save button is not enabled. it is grey out. Even If I select only external link and left other fields empty then also getting same error.

Comment: In my local version I cannot replicate what you are seeing (although it is 1905 rather than 1811).  When you change the LinkTo option, it should change the other fields ... so for LinkTo = Product you should see the product field, and for LinkTo = External Link you should see the URL field.  I am not sure why you see something different, perhaps customisations in your project?  Try with an uncustomised installation of the same 1811 release & see if it still behaves the same.  Also try clearing browser cache or a different browser

Comment: In my case even in my local and lower environments when I change the  LinkTo = product still I am seeing all other fields like category fields, content page fields and external link fields. Link editor fields are not updating as per LinkTo selection. same behavior in IE as well.

Answer (score 0):

We just had the same issue and found that we were overriding defaultCmsStructureTypeModeAttributeFilterList which caused the smartedit OOTB constraints on CMSLinkComponent to be lost. You must have some customization that is overriding the p:typeCode="CMSLinkComponent" restrictions defined in cmsfacades-structuretypes-mode-config-spring.xml